# How to check for any null values within a list before processing further?

Tags: c#

I'm passing a list to a method that operates on the list. However first I want to iterate over the list and check whether or not there are any null values within the list before any further processing takes place.

Initally I thought using the `IEnumerable.All()` method would help with this, however this method actually checks that all elements of the list satisfy a condition, I'd like to check each element in turn and if any are null then handle this.

This is the (non-working) code that I have already. I'm not sure how I would adapt this for use within an if statement condition.

```
if (questions == null || questions.Any() == false || questions.All(q => q == null))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Exception raised.");
}
```

Essentially I want to check:

1. Questions isn't null.
2. Questions isn't empty.
3. Any elements held within questions aren't null values.

The first two have been done, it's just the third.

Comment: Hmm, isn't it relevant: questions == null || questions.Any(q => q == null)) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this more concise version that uses `Any` and the [`?`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
bool valid = questions?.Any(q => q != null) == true;
if (!valid)
   throw new ArgumentException("Exception raised.");
```

The comparison with `true` is necessary to convert the `bool?` to `bool`. It also might be more efficient because it doesn't need to execute it multiple times(in case `questions` is a query). It also handles the case that `questions` is empty, then `Any` returns `false`.

Comment: instead of `== true`, wouldn't it be more correct to use `?? true`? i.e. "if I expect the result to be null I want the returned value to be true" instead of "If I expect the result to be null I want it converted to a boolean to compare with true"

Comment: @Default: Instead of  `== true` you could also use `?? false`. It's a matter of taste what you prefer. I find the `==` comparison more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to

```
if (questions != null && questions.Any() && questions.All(q => q != null))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest spliting in *two* tests - for `questions` itself (it must not be `null`) and for items within `questions` (there must be at least one not `null` item); your current code changed:

```
if (null == questions)
  throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(questions));
else if (questions.All(q => q == null))
  throw new ArgumentException("At least one not null question expected.",
                               nameof(questions));
```

Or even into *three*: when implementing a *contract*, in your case it is

> 1. `questions` isn't `null`.
> 2. `questions` isn't empty.
> 3. Any elements held within `questions` aren't `null` values.

try throw *separate exception* for each violation:

```
 if (null == questions)
   throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(questions));
 else if (!questions.Any())
   throw new ArgumentException("Questions must not be empty.",
                                nameof(questions)); 
 else if (questions.Any(item => null == item))
   throw new ArgumentException("Null questions are not allowed.",
                                nameof(questions));
```

Such kind implementation may appear *wordy* but it saves time when you are debugging (`"Exception raised."` provides no info when meaning of `"Questions must not be empty."` is evident).